# How do I play videos in a loop in the Samsung stock player?

Tags: video

I want to play a video repeatedly in the Samsung stock video player.  Is there a way?

Samsung Galaxy S3
OS: 4.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The stock video player on the S3 doesn't have this functionality. You can achieve it by installing another video app such as [VLC for Android](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html).

Comment: I guess VLC doesn't have the popup feature like the stock does it?  I want to play a video in the background on a loop while browsing. Will the audio keep playing on VLC in the background?

Comment: No, it doesn't, and no, it won't.

Comment: I downloaded VLC but I don't see the loop button!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by going to `Settings` => `Repeat` while the video is playing and enable it. ([source](http://www.galaxyforums.net/forum/off-topic-forum/1987-android-video-player.html#post22059))

Comment: I only see the option of "auto play off" under Settings while a video is playing. Where is "repeat"?

Comment: I think the linked thread is about a different video player.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IVideo Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.immsoftwares.ivideoplayer) , compatible for Android 3.0+, looping, child lock, brightness control, plays mov, flv, rmvb, mpg, mpeg and etc.